# how can I pass tagboardOptions dynamically?

Tags: javascript, tags, aem

instead of

```
<script>var tagboardOptions = {
tagboard:"namo/160501",
postCount: 3,
mobilePostCount: 4};
</script>
```

i want the

```
<script>var tagboardOptions = {
tagboard:"${properties.tagboardLocationPath"}, 
postCount: "${properties.postCount}", 
mobilePostCount: "${properties.mobilePostCount}"};
</script>
```

however it does not work...any ideas how to pass tag values dynamically?

Comment: please provide more context. what 'properties" is ? where is it defined ?

Comment: You have a typo at the end of the 2nd line - it should be `}",`

Comment: got it working guys....turns out the javascript part can not directly handle values taken from dialog box in cq5.Had taken those variables in HTML tag and could access them via JQuery.Thanks everyone for help.